# angular js ,knockoutjs ,kendo ui in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

i would like use my web application html5 and angular js ,knockoutjs ,kendo ui code for building hybrid mobile application by using xamarin .can any one tell how much flexible these technology with xamarin , also please provide me some documentation link for the hybrid xamarin mobile development .i try this technology with xamarin but it's not working.

Comment: Xamarin can serve an ASP website, but what you do with the javascript on that website(i.e. use angular, knockout.js) isn't terribly affected by what backend you choose. Likely you'll want to post a question showing your html code that isn't rendering and we can try and help you address that issue separately

Comment: If you wanna make bingings in xamarin, and you use xamarin forms, use XAML, but if you really wanna use JS see this http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/

Comment: If this is your requirement, then Xamarin is not the way to go. 
You should look into PhoneGap, which is more suitable for Hybrid applications based on web technologies.

Answer (score 0):

For a Hybrid app using AngularJS there is a framework called "Ionic".  The framework is based on the Cordova project and AngularJS.

I've built an app with it successfully.

Check out [this link](http://ionicframework.com/) and read their "get started" doc, it is a great framework.